# How to use macros to add an enum case?

Tags: rust, enums

I have an

```rust
enum EntryPoints {
    A(),
    B(),
}
```

Is it possible to create a macro to adds an enum case, like this?

```rust
use some_lib::make_callback;

enum EntryPoints {
    A(),
    B(),
    make_callback!(),
}
```

which expands to smething like

```rust
enum EntryPoints {
    A(),
    B(),
    SomeLibCallback(data: u64),
}
```

All my attempts to create a very simple example lead to syntax errors and I don't find anything on the web.

Comment: Rust forbids calling macros in that position. You may have to use a procedural attribute macro instead, or at least pass the enum declaration as an argument to the macro instead.

Answer (score 4):

You can't call macros within the body of an enum declaration, but you can pass the enum declaration into the macro instead:

```rust
macro_rules! make_callback {
    { enum $name:ident { $($inner:tt)* } } => {
        enum $name {
            SomeLibCallback(u64),
            $($inner)*
        }
    }
}

make_callback! { enum EntryPoints {
    A(),
    B(),
} }

// expansion
enum EntryPoints {
    SomeLibCallback(u64),

    A(),
    B(),
}
```

`{ $($inner:tt)* }` essentially just says to match any arbitrary sequence of tokens within the set of curly braces, and `$($inner)*` then expands that sequence back into the new enum body.